# mongodb inserts silently fail

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using `MongoDB` version 2.6.1 on windows platform, 64 bit, 16GB RAM (and using C# mongodb driver).
In my environment I insert ~15 documents (up to 128B each) every 10 seconds. Each insert action inserts a single document, and currently in my (single) collection I got 621,000 documents.
Lately, I noticed "holes" of few minutes in all inserts. And when I say "hole" i mean that in the same time range none of the document were inserted.

To debug, I printed the `WriteConcernResult` after each insert, and surprisingly, all of the inserted documents that are missing in the query, were successfully inserted:

```
WriteConcertResult: writeResult.Ok - True, writeResult.HasLastErrorMessage - False, writeResult.LastErrorMessage - , writeResult.ErrorMessage - , writeResult.Response - { "connectionId" : 57, "n" : 0, "syncMillis" : 0, "writtenTo" : null, "err" : null, "ok" : 1.0 }
```

To make sure I'm supposed to get exception on failure, I inserted the same document twice.
Now it just made things more interested since I indeed got the 'duplicate key error', but still couldn't find that document.
And to make sure I don't have "query" problem I checked if any document was even added to the collection when I caught the hole "in the act" and I found that none were added (even though the write-concern-result says Ok).

I then turned to mongo log (which I started with -vvvvv) and I couldn't find anything too suspicious:

```
2014-07-07T19:34:01.393+0300 [journal] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW
2014-07-07T19:34:01.393+0300 [journal] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW done startedAt: 5 n:4 0ms
2014-07-07T19:34:01.393+0300 [journal] groupCommit end
2014-07-07T19:34:02.219+0300 [conn8] PageFaultException thrown
2014-07-07T19:34:02.219+0300 [conn8] insert myDb.files ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:120 0ms
2014-07-07T19:34:02.219+0300 [conn8] run command myDb.$cmd { getlasterror: 1 }
2014-07-07T19:34:02.219+0300 [conn8] command myDb.$cmd command: getLastError { getlasterror: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:94 0ms
2014-07-07T19:34:02.219+0300 [conn8] run command myDb.$cmd { findAndModify: "reposInfo", query: { RepositorySizeInBytes: { $exists: true } }, update: { $inc: { RepositorySizeInBytes: 1018460 } }, new: true }
2014-07-07T19:34:02.219+0300 [conn8] Only one plan is available; it will be run but will not be cached. query: { RepositorySizeInBytes: { $exists: true } } sort: {} projection: {}, planSummary: COLLSCAN
2014-07-07T19:34:02.219+0300 [conn8] processing update :  query: { _id: ObjectId('538760d681536a0414a23bc9') } updated: { $inc: { RepositorySizeInBytes: 1018460 } } god: 0 upsert: 0 multi: 0 callLogOp: 1 fromMigration: 0 fromReplications: 0
2014-07-07T19:34:02.219+0300 [conn8] Using idhack: { _id: ObjectId('538760d681536a0414a23bc9') }
2014-07-07T19:34:02.219+0300 [conn8] update validate options --  updatedFields: Fields:[ RepositorySizeInBytes,] immutableAndSingleValueFields.size:0 fromRepl: 0 validate:1
2014-07-07T19:34:02.219+0300 [conn8] UpdateResult --  upserted: {} modifiers: 1 existing: 1 numDocsModified: 1 numMatched: 1
2014-07-07T19:34:02.219+0300 [conn8] update result:  upserted: {} modifiers: 1 existing: 1 numDocsModified: 1 numMatched: 1
2014-07-07T19:34:02.219+0300 [conn8] using modified query to return the new doc: { _id: ObjectId('538760d681536a0414a23bc9') }
2014-07-07T19:34:02.219+0300 [conn8] Using idhack: query: { _id: ObjectId('538760d681536a0414a23bc9') } sort: {} projection: {}
2014-07-07T19:34:02.219+0300 [conn8] command myDb.$cmd command: findAndModify { findAndModify: "reposInfo", query: { RepositorySizeInBytes: { $exists: true } }, update: { $inc: { RepositorySizeInBytes: 1018460 } }, new: true } update: { $inc: { RepositorySizeInBytes: 1018460 } } ntoreturn:1 nscanned:1 nscannedObjects:1 nMatched:1 nModified:1 fastmod:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:215 reslen:144 0ms
```

I wasn't sure if the "PageFaultException thrown" part was related to the problem, but after reading about this exception I understood it might be normal and then I saw this exception also before real success inserts, so I moved on with that.

Even though the write-concern-result tell me everything is OK, I still checked `serverStatus` and `currentOp` for possible locking action, but couldn't find anything strange there.

And suggestions on how to better debug this situation?
boring info:
- mongodb instance is created using `new MongoClient(addr)` > `client.GetServer()` > `server.GetDatabase(dbName)` (so write-concern is enabled on default).
- The collection is totally standard (not a capped-collection, not sharded, without replica set)
- The _id used for the inserted documents is `BinData`
- The mongo process takes (according to Task Manager) 38,148K RAM, only 20% of the server RAM is in use.
- The mongo version is updated, and is 64 bit.

**--Update--**

When I search for the document by its BinData _id, I can (somehow) get it, but it's invisible for any other way.
For instance, when I search this:
`db.files.find({"_id": BinData(0, "alnYNFB8XxGo+KB8A70vCw==")})`
I get (first object):

```
{
        "_id" : BinData(0,"alnYNFB8XxGo+KB8A70vCw=="),
        "dId" : "537cbafd81536a0aa03f6be3",
        "cN" : 1,
        "ty" : 0,
        "sT" : ISODate("2014-07-08T06:53:20.534Z"),
        "eT" : ISODate("2014-07-08T06:53:30.845Z"),
        "hS" : 40,
        "sId" : 1
}
```

But when I search by "sT", I find None (when I do the same search by "sT" for documents that I see in collection then I can find them).
What da...

**-- Update (to Asya's comment) --**
Search by "sT" example for "good" document:

```
>> goodDate = ISODate("2014-07-08T06:55:59.056Z");
>> db.files.find({"sT": goodDate})
```

I get the returned document. Then I do:

```
>> missDate = ISODate("2014-07-08T06:53:20.534Z")
>> db.files.find({"sT": missDate})
```

Find nothing!

Another example:

```
>> db.files.find({"sT": {$gte: missDate}})
```

first result starts with "sT" : `ISODate("2014-07-08T06:55:41.446Z")`

the thing is, like I said before, after the log tells me the insert was successful, I'm checking `db.files.find().length()` and it's the same.
I even did a for loop on find() and searched for the missing document _id and STILL couldn't find it.

**--update--**
after some tests (thanks to mongo forum), we decided this issue should come as a ticket.
so a ticket was posted in mongo r&d community. I'll continue and update here when we know for sure what's going on.

Comment: show your search for that "sT" value that returns no documents please.

Comment: is this a stand-alone mongod - no replication, no sharding?

Comment: what's >> prompt? are you in mongo shell here or using one of the drivers?

Comment: like I said in the question, no replication, no sharding, just standalone.  and indeed, i run it from the shell

Comment: it looks like this question is a deeper problem, so i continue this thread on mongo forum, and update findings here.

Comment: Can you give a link to the issue you created for this?

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SUPPORT-1062